# merge in sas - union in python

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am converting sas program into python
one of such operation is merging two tables
one of the tables as 25 columns and other one has 2 columns
sas merges this without any issues
where pyspark union needs to have same number of columns?
how to approach this problem
full join gives diff number of records

```
 Table 1:
 df.printSchema()
 |-- Port1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Port12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col10: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col13: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col14: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col15: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col16: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col7: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col18: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col19: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col20: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col21: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Col22: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Col23: string (nullable = true)



Table 2 :
df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- Port1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Port2: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you post schema's for both tables? if possible provide sample input and output.

Comment: Added Schema of both tables

Comment: Show example input data, expected output data, code you used and explain or show how it does not match what you need/want.